# Core Data this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I had to add Core data to my existing project, but all I have is one entity and one attribute to it. I have an entity named "Places" and an attribute named `name`. I seem to be getting `SIGABRT` at the `cell.nameLabel.text` line:

```
NSManagedObject *Item = [placesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Item valueForKey:@"name"]
```

I have imported "Places.h" which is the NSManagedObject subclass. I have no idea what could possible be the matter.

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the FULL error:

```
    2014-07-30 08:56:11.415 FindItHere[1216:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x1f7dc> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01d5c1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01adb8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01debfe1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x0158ec7a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x014fbdfd _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 81
    5   Foundation                          0x014fb437 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 260
    6   FindItHere                          0x0000f6dc -[FindTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 508
    7   UIKit                               0x0068711f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
    8   UIKit                               0x006871f3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
    9   UIKit                               0x00668ece -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2428
    10  UIKit                               0x0067d6a5 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
    11  UIKit                               0x005fd964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01aed82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    13  QuartzCore                          0x04c1145a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    14  QuartzCore                          0x04c05244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    15  QuartzCore                          0x04c050b0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    16  QuartzCore                          0x04b6b7fa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    17  QuartzCore                          0x04b6cb85 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    18  QuartzCore                          0x04b6d258 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01d2436e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01d242bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01d02254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01d019d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01d017eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x031745ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x0317442b GSEventRun + 104
    26  UIKit                               0x0058ef9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  FindItHere                          0x0000c54d main + 141
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x02e0d70d start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

And this error occurs at this EXACT line:

```
[cell.nameLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Item valueForKey:@"name"]]];
```

EDIT #2: Here is how I populated my array in the viewDidLoad:

```
placesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;

[placesArray addObject:@"ATM"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Park"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Restaurant"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Library"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Gas Station"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Florist"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Cafe"];
```

Comment: Are you certain (really certain) that the object you're receiving into Item is in fact an instance of your class? Are you certain that you've not defined the name property with an upper case N in the declaration (Name vs name)?

Comment: Post the full error. What class does the error talk about?

Comment: NSManagedObject is neither a dictionary not an array, that is why you are getting the error,

Comment: Please show us how you're populating `placesArray`. We need to see how you're fetching from CoreData.

Comment: Why are you trying to use NSManagedObject *Item? Look at how you're populating `placesArray`. You're literally only putting `NSStrings` inside. You're going to run into a run-time error when you try to convert `NSString` to `Item`. No where in your code are you generating any `CoreData` objects. What is happening is you're actually running `cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [@"ATM" valueForKey:@"name"]]`. This doesn't make any sense - either add `Item` objects to your `placesArray` or don't try to use `Item valueForKey:@"name"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you've provided, you actually aren't using CoreData at all.

```
placesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[placesArray addObject:@"ATM"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Park"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Restaurant"];
```

The above code shows that instead of using your CoreData Entity `Item`, you instead are just using a flat out `NSString`. This makes it crash, because when you do the following:

```
NSManagedObject *Item = [placesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Item valueForKey:@"name"]
```

You are doing the equivalent of:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [{NSString} valueForKey:@"name"]
```

You have two solutions:

1) Drop CoreData because it doesn't look like you're actually using it. Instead of `Item` being a `NSManagedObject` you can just make it a regular `NSObject`. This is the quicker solution and may even make more sense for you. This makes your code the following:

```
placesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < items.count; i++)
{
  Item *newItem = [Item new];
  newItem.name = @"ATM";
  ...
  [placesArray addObject:newItem];
}
```

and

```
Item *cellItem = [placesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
cell.nameLabel.text = cellItem.name;
```

2) Have you set up a `ManagedObjectContext`, `PersistantSToreCoordinator`, etc? If not, then look up tutorials on how to set up CoreData properly in your project.  If you have, then you need to get the NSManagedObjectContext and do one of the following:

- Detect if it's in your CoreData database. If it isn't, then you need to do an `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` and save your context after. If it is in your database, then you need to do a `FetchRequest`. [Look at this Guide for how to do it.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a class called Places when you generate the NSManagedObject subclass for your data model   you should be using that subclass instead of what you coded: like so:

```
 Places_instance = (Places *) [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Places_instance.name];
```

Suggest you study the CoreData Sample Codes from Apple particularly how to use the FetchResultsController etc.

Answer (score 0):

`placesArray` contains instance of `NSString` instead of instance of `NSManagedObject`

Answer (score 0):

The first line in the error message says

```
2014-07-30 08:56:11.415 FindItHere[1216:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x1f7dc> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
```

That tells you that the object you sent the message to is an `__NSCFConstantString`, which is a subclass of `NSString`. What that means is that even though you did this:

```
NSManagedObject *Item = [placesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

...the object you got from the array is actually an `NSString`, not an `NSManagedObject`.

This indicates that at least some of the objects in `placesArray` are strings, not managed objects. Why that happens depends on the code where you created that array (or added to it, if it's mutable).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are adding `NSString` objects into your `placesArray`, rather than `Place` objects.

Instead do:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
Place *place1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Place" inManagedObjectContext:context];
place1.name = @"ATM";

placesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[placesArray addObject:place1];
```

Also it's not clear what `Item` is in your question. I'm going to assume you meant `Place` rather than `Item`.

And if you have imported `Places.h`, the `NSManagedObject` subclass, it should work fine.

Comment: Your code will have it always inserting a new object instead of reading from CoreData if it's currently in the system